# How can I change playback music between game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to write a code to change playback music between the game. main playback music is correct and work, but I don't know how to change it between the game.
I'm trying to stop it and set new playback, but it does't work.
I use this code for the main playback:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pygame.mixer.stop()` which stops playback of all sound channels.
Then you can load a new music and play it like you are doing now:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('newmusic.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Of course you need some algorithm to decide when to call these functions.
You could use a timer to force a new music after a given amount of time, or an event game: for example when the player enters in a new area of the game you trigger an custom event to change the music.

Here is the full [pygame.music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) documentation.